# TLS: Which is the AES key?

Tags: ssl, aes, rsa

I'm programming a very small TLS client, to use it together with my SMTP client. The SMTP client already works well, but I want to use it together with a mail provider like GMX oder GoogleMail. So I need TLS.

The first handshake messages are already working:

1. Send "Client Hello"
2. Receive "Server Hello"
3. Receive Server Certificate
4. Receive "Server Hello Done"
5. Send "Client Key Exchange"
6. Send "Change Cipher Spec"

The next step would be sending the "Finished" message. But I'm a bit confused of the different keys.

I have already calculated the master-secret like described in the RFC. Like the RFC describes, the "Finished" message contains a "verify data" which is created throw

```
PRF(master_secret, finished_label, Hash(handshake_messages))
```

I seem this is already working correctly. Next I thing I should encrypt the "verify data". Is that correct? I'm using the cipher suite TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256. For encrypting data with AES-256 I have to set a key of 32 bytes. But which key do I have to use here? The master-secret? But the master-secret is 48 bytes long!?

I hope someone can help me and clear my confusion.

Comment: It's all spelled out in [RFC 5246, section 6.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-6.3).

Comment: Thanks. I must have missed that.I'm going to read it and reply if I have any questions.